# How could I make index still when I delete element in Array.each loop?

Tags: ruby

As I know , when I delete an element in Array.The index still move forward. How can I make the index still when I delete elements in the loop?

Below is just an example. In this example, I hope to delete all the elements with unique num ,but finally num '2' is still left.

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :num
  attr_accessor :job
  def initialize(num,job)
    @num = num
    @job = job
  end
end

a = []

a << Test.new(1,'jobA')
a << Test.new(2,'jobB')
a << Test.new(1,'jobC')
a << Test.new(3,'jobD')

b = Hash.new

a.each_with_index do |i,index|
  #puts i.num,index
  if b[i.num] == nil
    b[i.num] = true
    a.delete(i)
  end
end

a.each do |i|
  puts i.num,i.job
end

# it shows:
# 2 jobB
# 1 jobC

# I hope to get only:
# 1 jobC
```

In this new example , I hope 'jobC' with the duplicate num '1' left, and hope other unique num elements deleted.

Hope someone can help, Thank you !

I use delete_if finally , Thanks for all your replies to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)

- This method allows you to specify a test - if the element passes the test, it is deleted.
- #clear is for removing all elements unconditionally

You shouldn't be removing elements from within an iterator such as #each

Comment: If you want to delete all elements, you should be using clear. If you want to delete specific elements via a 'filter' block, that's when you use #reject or #delete_if

Comment: I think you are right, I shouldn't remove element in #each. I used C programming logic in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I understand your logic for this operation correctly or maybe you need to rethink why you approaching it this way, but something like this might work for you instead of `.each`:

```
a = (1..5).to_a

a.reject! do |c| 
  puts c # or perform other operations on the element
  true
end

puts a.inspect
```

Comment: I changed my example to make my question more clear, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep that array of same length and replace all the values with nil then

```
a = some_array

Array.new(a.length)

#[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Or

If you want to delete only some values and also preserve the index of other elements then do

For Ex: Deleting even numbers

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

a.each_with_index { |num, index| a[index] = nil if num % 2 == 0 } 

#[1, nil, 3, nil, 5]
```

Comment: I changed my example to make my question more clear, thank you for your reply.

Comment: @wonderflow you question is still not clear... Just update it with expected output..

Comment: I'm sorry. Is it clear now? I add the expected output

Comment: @wonderflow what about 3, jobD and also you want to keep the last occurence of duplicate num ?

Comment: @wonderflow you want to delete all the uniques values and keep the last occurence of the duplicate values right?

Comment: in this case 3,jobD is deleted. I hope to delete all the unique elements and keep all the duplicate ones .

Comment: I use delete_if finally. Thanks you very much.